# Can Cantrips/Spells alter the environment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

For instance, a druid's *Thorn Whip*...can I cast the cantrip to manipulate the environment (like to pull a door open)?

It doesn't specifically say but I'm rather new to D&D as it is so I figured I'd make sure!

Comment: This question is a bit too broad.  Please narrow the scope of this question (and the title of the question) to address the specific spell/cantrip that you have a  question about.  Rescoping this question to only ask about the issue with Thorn Whip will vastly improve the question and retain the "good question" criteria usually used here.

Comment: Given the mold earth directly does affect it, I think your question is better outlined as "can combat cantrips/spells have non-combat implications." Which is definitely broad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Can Cantrips or Spells alter the environment?**

Yes, absolutely. *Thaumaturgy* (cantrip) will make the ground shake, *Sleet Storm* (level 3) will make freezing rain fall, *Knock* (2nd level) will unlock a door, and *Wish* (9th level) will do literally *anything*.

**Can *Thorn Whip* open a door?**

Nope, not as written. The spell's description (PHB282) says it "lashes out toward a *creature*.... If the attack hits, the *creature* [is pulled]. (emphasis mine)"

(Implied question)
**So how do I use my spells and cantrips in cool and inventive ways?**

Read the spell descriptions carefully, mull them over, and keep an eye out for unusual situations to use them in. Pre-clear edge-interpretations with a DM, and be prepared to have to explain yourself. But it's definitely a common part of the game to try to use spells in novel ways--have fun with it!

This may include pushing and prodding at the boundaries of the rules-as-written; that's a thing some tables and GMs are really happy with, some absolutely disavow. As @Jonathon Wisnoski puts it:

> I think using thorn whip on an object (in a non exploitive way) is exactly the sort of thing creative DMs like and indeed the designers tried to encourage. There is a huge difference between trying to wiggle around the rules to optimize your character, and playing loose with the rules to do reasonable, cool, and roleplay-y things that technicality do not work within the rules.... There is this entire Reddit thread with actual DMs and players extolling the virtues of [allowing thorn whip to be used in creative illegal ways](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/2kpo4l/thorn_whip_cantrip_as_a_hookshot/).